# How to pop an arbitrary element from a list?

Tags: list, lisp

**Q:** how do I pop an arbitrary element from a list?

Given the list `'(a b c d e)`, `pop` returns `a` and destructively
modifies the list to `'(b c d e)`.  How can I generalize this
function so I could pop an arbitrary element (say, `c`)?

I'm almost sure I've seen this in a library somewhere, but can't
remember where.

Comment: An afterthought: maybe you were just thinking of `delq`?  Do you want to delete by position or value (in the latter case you probably don't need the value returned).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply `(pop (nthcdr n my-list))`:

```
(let ((x '(a b c d e)))
  (list (pop (nthcdr 2 x))
        x))
;; => (c (a b d e))
```

Comment: I think it's funny that I wrote a little function to `setcar` and `setcdr` of the `nthcdr` and was thinking of an appropriate name for the function and once I thought "pop-nthcdr" realized "oh! you could just write that!"  </facepalm>